# Is luck also included in damage calculation to an ore mine?

Tags: fantasy-life

I just arrived at a new place, and luckily me Mine skill and equipment was sufficient to mine the new ore. In the sweet spot, I hit for roughly 18-21 damage, in the right rhythm. Then I went to the village there, and bought a new charm, with more (magic) defence, but also +10 luck. Also I levelled up somewhere in between, so maybe that has something to do with it as well (I didn't spent the points).

Now the same ores are damaged up to 22 (and fairly often too). Is luck also taken into account when the damage is calculated? Or is it the level up that did the extra damage or (unlikely) the extra (magic) defence?

Comment: Hmm, something similar happened with woodcutting, but without equipping other items or levelling up. Only thing different was (apart from the tree, species was the same) that I levelled up woodcutting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, luck plays *no part* in mining damage. To test, I reset my stats to bring my luck down to 5. Then, with the following setup, I mined some dark ores:

```
Mining   - 133
Strength -  74
Luck     -   5
```

I consistently did 19-21 damage (with rhythmic "heavy" hits) on five deposits.

So, I raised my luck to 50 and added a +10 luck charm for a total of 60. Damage remained between 19-21 for every hit. Raised luck again to 110 (including charm), and no difference. Every hit still between 19-21.

I can't tell you what caused your damage to raise. I'm pretty sure leveling without allocating points doesn't change anything except max HP. Magic defense shouldn't play any part it in either. However, I'm *very* confident now that it wasn't the luck.

Comment: Thanks for investigating it! I didn't finish the game yet so I couldn't reset my stats, but this was an excellent idea to test.